# Prism + Xamarin.Forms Project error after closing app on Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am developing an app using Prism and Xamarin Forms. I used Prism template to create the project in Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

Here is the app.cs page

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("BasePage");
}

protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<BasePage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainNavigationPage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MilkPurchasePage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TruckSheetPage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LocalSalePage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MembersPage>();
}
```

Now `BasePage` contains Hamburger menu and from there it will navigate to `MilkPurchasePage`

Now everything works when I run the project on mobile but once I close the app I get

```
Unfortunately , MilkApp.Droid has stopped.
```

I only added user interface. No background code has been added other than navigation.

I tried to debug bug I am unable to get it in visual studio. I checked all errors in Error Settings too. But still I am unable to solve it.

Why I am getting this ?

Comment: Go into your Visual Studio settings, by opening the Tools menu, click Options, expand the Debugging node, and click Output Window. Set the logging output a bit higher there, run your app, produce the error and check the output window for some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with Xamarin.Forms.  They fixed this in the past, but it looks like they may have had a regression.  You can easily reproduce this by creating a standard XF application.  You should submit this as a bug to Xamarin.

Comment: Ok I will submit. Thanks for the info.